# Find the 4 closest positions of X and Y on a list

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, list, sorting

I have the following class :

```
class IBeacon {
    var x = Int()
    var y = Int()
    var ID = Int()

   init(id: Int, x :Int, y: Int) {
       self.x = x
       self.y = y
       self.ID = id
   }
}
```

and in another class I have a *beacons list*:

```
var listIBeacon = [IBeacon]()
```

Problem: I get my coordinate X (`Int`) and Y (`Int`) and I would know the 4 *closest* `IBeacon` in the list `listIBeacon` to me.

Comment: Not quite sure what your issue is? Are you trying to calculate the closest beacons based on a specified IBeacon instance? Or are you trying to determine the 4 that are closest to each other inside your array?

Comment: sort the beacons array based on the accuracy or RSSI, you will get the closest one at the first and the largest at the last of the array. Then you can retrieve the first four beacons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a helper function to compute *distances* between beacons (we can drop the pesky *square root* since we are only comparing distances):

```
extension IBeacon {
    func distanceSquared(to beacon: IBeacon) -> Int {
        let dx = beacon.x - self.x
        let dy = beacon.y - self.y
        return dx*dx + dy*dy
    }
}
```

then *sort* using the `distanceSquared` function we just implemented:

```
var listIBeacon = [IBeacon]()
let myBeacon: IBeacon = ...
listIBeacon.sort {
    let dist0 = myBeacon.distanceSquared(to: $0)
    let dist1 = myBeacon.distanceSquared(to: $1)
    return dist0 < dist1
}
```

finally, filter the *closest* 4 beacons:

```
let closestBeacons = Array(listIBeacon.prefix(4))
```

Comment: I would recommend using `.prefix(4)`

Comment: @Alexander BTW, the `Array` API is just *too* rich for a recovering Java guy like me, haha :-)

Comment: @PauloMattos Note that prefix returns an Array Slice